# Does Stokes Thoerem say extend to closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: vector-analysis

Does Stokes Thoerem  say $\oint_{\partial R} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}  = \iint_R \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} $ for closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

My issue is that most statements of Stoke's theorem and proofs seem to imply that the surface does indeed have a non-empty boundary.  Note I am **not** talking about applying Stoke's theorem to closed surfaces by breaking up the surface, hence showing that surface integral of a curl is always $0$.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine what you are talking about, then.

Comment: @MartinArgerami e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183007/improper-use-of-stokes-and-divergence-theorem-find-the-problem?rq=1 seems to be applied here.

Comment: You explicitly say in your question that you are **not** talking about that.

Comment: See here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606419/using-stokes-theorem-to-show-the-integral-of-curl-f-is-zero-over-closed-s/3606579#3606579

Comment: @MartinArgerami What I mean to say is that Stoke's theorem only makes sense for open surfaces with piecewise smooth boundary, and that to make a conclusion about a closed surface we could apply the theorem to reach a corollary.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter My  real issue is whether Stokes theorem can be applied in the following manner: https://imgur.com/sMBnwnx where $S$ is the surface of the unit sphere.